# Running ActionBarActivity instead of Fragment on DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, fragment

I want to making DrawerLayout for my new android app. But I need to use activity on same activity.

How can I handle it, I have code looks like this :

my_activity.java; (has a lot of code for list of menu, swipe vs, But I just add lines of my problems)

```
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
```

Here is my problem. I want to run activity file at this step but I cant. I wanna show some activity file case : 0, I tried everything I know But I cant do it.
**ACTUALLY I m a bit of confused for this fragment & activity problems**.

Thank you for helps.

Comment: I couldn't really understand what do you want and what is going on with your app.

Comment: Hi I making swipe menu(Navigation Drawer) on my android app. I want to use activity instead of fragment. In the code I just running new HomeFragment() meaning that incldue this class when I click menu link. But I wanna run activity file when I click the menu link. I hope you'll understand me. Sorry my english. Im still learning.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I got you. Gonna post an answer, see if it fits your needs !

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your activity xml (the one you wanna use with the Navigation Drawer) must contain a `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`
 as its root element and a listview (last on the xml hierarchy)

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

In your activity you should have:

```
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        ListView drawerList;
        ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
        ...
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
                    R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.Open, R.string.Close);

            drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
 drawerList.setAdapter(new youradaptertype());

        drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {

                switch (arg2) {

                    case 0:
                        Intent l = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                FriendActivity.class);
                        startActivity(l);
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        Intent j = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RequestActivity.class);
                        startActivity(j);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                SettingsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;

                    ...
                }

                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
            }
        });
```

Inside each "case" statement, to start an activity you should use the Intent and start a new activity. If you simply wanna change fragments (instead of starting new activities) inside the "case" you should to something like this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(YOUR_ROOT_VIEW_ID, new fragmenttobeinstantiated())
                //optinal
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

See if it helps !